# BIRT report shrinking issue

Tags: .net, birt

I am facing the pdf output issue. The issue comes up when i login to the application for the first time and ran the report. The report was shrinking. When i ran the same report second time then report was not shrinking. Please help me on this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAkAf.png)

Comment: Attached the screenshot of this report. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAkAf.png

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Probably this is not a BIRT problem, but an issue with the PDF viewer integration.